# Zend_Form_Element conditional class on HtmlTag decorator (on errors)

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-decorators

In one of my web projects I'm building with Zend Framework, I have a form with the following structure:

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label />
        <div>
          <input />
          <small>Helptext</small>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="error"> <!-- This one has errors -->
        <label />
        <div>
          <input />
          <ul class="errors">
            <li>Error message</li>
          </ul>
          <small>Helptext</small>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I am able to build this structure using the standard decorators of Zend Framework, except for one thing.  I need to be able to add the `error` class on the li of elements that have validation errors and such.  I use the following validators:

- ViewHelper
- Errors
- HtmlTag (`'tag' => 'small', 'placement' => 'append'`)
- HtmlTag (`'tag' => 'div'`)
- Label
- HtmlTag (`'tag' => 'li'`)

The default validators are disabled. (I use `$element->setDecorators()` in the `init()` method of a custom form class that extends Zend_Form.) So my problem boils down to adding the class "error" to the last decorator when there are any validation errors on the element.

Does anybody know a handy way to do this?  I guess I could override the default render method of the elements to check if there are any validation errors and then add a class option to a named decorator, but that is not really elegant.  I'm wondering if there is some standardised way to do this...  I am using Zend Framework 1.11, by the way.

Cheers,
Eric

Tl;dr:

How to add a class option to a HtmlTag decorator on a Zend_Form_Element when there are validation errors?

Answer (score 1):

When you only want the error class for a couple of elements, you could simply use a callback for the class attribute. This would look something like the following:

```
$form->addElement('text', 'test', array(
    'decorators' => array(
        'ViewHelper',
        array(
            'HtmlTag',
            array(
                'tag' => 'li',
                'class' => array(
                    'callback' => function($decorator) {
                        if($decorator->getElement()->hasErrors()) {
                            return 'error';
                        }
                    }
                )
            )
        )
    )
));
```

If you use PHP5.2 or earlier, you need to replace the closure with an array based callback (e.g. `array($this,  'getLiClassAttribute')`)

If you want to use the error class for all your elements, you are better off writing a custom decorator.